# Windows phone 8.1 Sound effects javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a small game for windows 8.1 with Javascript and HTML5. I am having a small problem, on click I would like to play a sound, here is the code which I have written.

```
var sfx_click = new Audio("/Sfx/jump.ogg");
sfx_click.volume = 1;
sfx_click.play();
```

The above piece of code is not playing the sound. I even tried with Sound.js,
`createjs.Sound.play("/Sfx/jump.ogg", createjs.Sound.INTERUPT_ANY);`

Which did not work. I would like to know what I might be missing here.
I have even tried changing the format to .mp3
Should I enable anything in appmanifest??
Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append the sfx_click audio the body of your page.

```
var sfx_click = new Audio();
document.body.appendChild(sfx_click);
sfx_click.src = "/Sfx/jump.ogg";
sfx_click.play();
```

The code above works fine in IE with mp3 files. I haven´t tested it with ogg files.